# When using .NET to connect to AWS Redshift Serverless, tables I created cannot be seen

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-serverless

I am using .NET 6.0 with Visual Studio + AWS Explorer plugin that has my credential saved. I created a simple table consisting of first name and last name.

```
create table name(
firstname varchar(200),
lastnamename varchar(200)
);
```

Then insert 2 data points:

```
INSERT INTO name VALUES ('jacky', 'chen'), ('elon', 'musk')
```

I see the names show up when I query them.

- The workgroup is `preview`.
- The database is `dev`.
- The schema is `public`.
- The table name is `name`.

[image]

Here is the .NET code I am using to access it:

```
using Amazon.RedshiftDataAPIService;
using Amazon.RedshiftDataAPIService.Model;
using Amazon.Runtime.Internal;

var client = new AmazonRedshiftDataAPIServiceClient(region: Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

ListDatabasesRequest listDatabase = new ListDatabasesRequest();
listDatabase.WorkgroupName = "preview";
listDatabase.Database = "dev";
var temp = client.ListDatabasesAsync(listDatabase);
Task.WaitAll(temp);


ListSchemasRequest listSchemas = new ListSchemasRequest();
listSchemas.WorkgroupName = "preview";
listSchemas.Database = "dev";
var temp3 = client.ListSchemasAsync(listSchemas);
Task.WaitAll(temp3);

ListTablesRequest listTables = new ListTablesRequest();
listTables.WorkgroupName = "preview";
listTables.Database = "dev";
listTables.SchemaPattern = "%public";
var temp2 = client.ListTablesAsync(listTables);
foreach (var table in temp2.Result.Tables)
{
    if (table.Name == "name")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("found");
    }
}

Task.WaitAll(temp2);

Console.ReadLine();
```

`temp` and `temp3` variables does see my database (dev) and schema (public). However, `temp2` result has nothing.

[image]

Can anyone help me figure out why my manually created table will not be seen from my code?
However, the same code can see the tables from `sample_data_dev` workgroup provided by Amazon as a Redshift example.

I tried creating another table inside `sample_data_dev/tickit` example and loaded it with same names data points. It had 7 tables to begin with. After I created another table, I have 8 total. When I run my code, I only see the original 7 tables. It seems anything I created manually cannot be seen from my .NET code. Very baffled. Any help would be nice.

Comment: Hi, did you solve this yet?

Comment: Are your credentials actually the same between Visual Studio and dotnet? The SDK will pickup your default AWS profile or whatever is set via env variables, which may be different from the credentials used in the AWS Explorer.